# How to get an Object from a Set if you know that there is only one Object in it?

Tags: java, set

Imagine a code like:

```
Set<Car> carObject;
```

Now I know that there is only one object in this Set. How do I get it properly?

```
Car myCar = carObject.whatMethod ?
```

???

Edit: Thanks for the great answers.

I know there is only one object as I have an

```
if(carObject.size ... )
```

check just before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
carObject.iterator().next();
```

Answer (score 10):

If you **really** know that there is one element:

```
Car myCar = carObjet.iterator().next();
```

Anyway, I'd go sure and do:

```
Iterator<Car> it = carObjet.iterator();
if (it.hasNext()) {
    Car myCar = it.next();
}
```

Comment: you should use the same iterator instance for the hasNext() and the next call()

Comment: @SebastianBaltes: Thanks, that was a copy/paste mistake, fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an array:

```
Car myCar = carObject.toArray(new Car[1])[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Because a set has no direct access to its members by an index, you must iterate over the set, that seems to be the cheapest:

```
Car myCar = carObject.iterator().next();
```

This should be generally prefered over transforming the set into an array or list, because an iterator does not copy the data structure.

Answer (score 1):

If you know your `Set` has `n` elements and you want to access the `i`th one:

```
carSet.toArray(new Car[n])[i];
```